# How to get cookie value from user's browser and email it to webmaster after form submit

Tags: php, cookies

I have a form on my site which users are filling with name and email, and then it generates an email to the webmaster notifying of user submitting their info. There's also a cookie placed which is for referral tracking, how can I also include that data in the email out to the webmaster?

```
<?php
///subscribe form
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'] ;
$recipient = "myemail@email.com"; ///  Webmaster address

if (isset($_POST['email']))
  {
  //Send Mail To Webmaster
  $email = $_POST['email'] ;
  $subject = ' Enviralizer: Someone Just Requested More Info';
  $message = 'Your new lead info is below: '; 
  $message .= "\r\n\nName: " .$firstname;          
  $message .= "\r\n\nEmail: " .$email;  
  mail("$recipient", $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $recipient);
  header("Location: http://thanks.com");
  }
 ?>
```

I know the script is not the best secured thing in the world, I will take care of that later, I just need a quick fix for a bigger script tracking issue I'm trying to resolve as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for `$_COOKIE['name_of_cookie']` ?